# WPF - Print content on same page

Tags: wpf, printing

I have a requirement to print the WPF form contents on a Save button click. The content is plain text and will be name value pairs on each line. I don't need page breaks on consecutive Saves.

I have tried out the samples for PrintDialog, FlowDocument and FixedDocument and could not avoid the page break. 
Is there any particular setting I am missing ? 
Any alternative to PrintDialog ?

Code:

```
 Paragraph myParagraph = new Paragraph();
 myParagraph.Margin = new Thickness(0);
 **myParagraph.BreakPageBefore = false;**
 foreach (string line in textToPrint.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None))
 {              
     myParagraph.Inlines.Add(new Run(line));              
 }
 flowDocument.Blocks.Add(myParagraph);
 DocumentPaginator paginator = ((IDocumentPaginatorSource)flowDocument).DocumentPaginator;
 printDialog.PrintDocument(paginator, "Test Page");
```

Answer (score 0):

A new Print job (Document) starts with a new page as far as I know. If you don't want page breaks gather all the values you want to print and then print them.

Comment: If you don't want page breaks gather all the values you want to print and then print them. Should I be using Win32 API for this or its possible in C#/WPF itself ?

Comment: At the moment you are creating a Document each time the user presses the button. Instead, create a single Document and add data to that document. When all the data has been added, print the document.

Comment: I need to print after each Save. Even if I try to reuse the Document object and print only the new content I have to make sure it targets the same page and does not insert a page break in between. The target printer is most likely a dot matrix printer.